# remove not matching rows from a df by checking in another df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 data frames. I want to remove items from the second data frame which is not present in the first data frame.

df1

```
a  

tom
mat
stuart
```

df2

```
b

tom
mat
max
```

Expected df after removing not matching value of b from a :

df1

```
a  

tom
mat
stuart
```

df2

```
b

tom
mat
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to remove conflicting values?

Comment: yes, but only in df2

Answer (score 0):

These are not looking like a dataframes to me .. Given your input, here is one way (of the many) achieving this

```
>>> s1

0       tom
1      matt
2    stuart
dtype: object

>>> s2

0     tom
1    matt
2     max
dtype: object

>>> s1[s1 == s2]
0     tom
1    matt
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest an inner join, like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':['tom','mat','stuart']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'b':['tom','mat','max']})
df2 = pd.merge(df1,df2, left_on='a', right_on='b', how = 'inner')
```